# MariaDB Node.js-Connector insert a value and use the default value

Tags: express, mariadb

I have a MariaDB database in conjuction with an Express.js backend and therefore use the MariaDB provided [Node.js Connector](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/). I Initialized a Database with a Table that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Threads` (
    `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    `post` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Using the Node.js-Connector in my Backend, I want to insert some data to this table and use the default values for *"created_at"* and *"updated_at"*.

I was thinking of something like this:

```js
const insertThreadQuery = 'INSERT INTO Threads VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
con = await pool.getConnection();
const result = await con.query(insertThreadQuery, [null, "title", "post", null, null]);
```

Which obivously throws an error that tells me, that I cannot insert null for these Values `((conn=4, no: 1048, SQLState: 23000) Column 'updated_at' cannot be null sql: INSERT INTO Threads VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) - parameters:[null,'title','post',null,null])`

My question is: How can I insert an entry like I was showing before, but instead of inserting "null" insert something else so my columns *created_at* and *updated_at* use the default value?

Comment: Why don't you pass DEFAULT instead of NULL? `INSERT INTO Threads VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)`.

Comment: @GeorgRichter Wow, I actually did not think of that, thank you!

Comment: @GeorgRichter but how would my con.query() function call look like? Would it change to `con.query(insertThreadQuery, ["title", "post"])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use DEFAULT values, then pass DEFAULT instead of NULL.

```
const insertThreadQuery = 'INSERT INTO Threads VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)';
con = await pool.getConnection();
const result = await con.query(insertThreadQuery, ["title", "post"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and came across this question, but the answer did not work in my case, because I did not know ahead of time which columns would have values and which would have required their default values.

Using your same `CREATE TABLE` statement, you could prepare and execute the query like so:

```
const query = await con.prepare( 'INSERT INTO Threads VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, COALESCE( ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), COALESCE( ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) )' );

query.execute( [ null, 'The Title', 'The Post', new Date( '2000-01-01 00:00:00' ), null ] );
```

This would insert the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` into the `updated_at` column.

If the columns in question had scalar default values, as opposed to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, as was the case in my problem, you can use the column name instead in the COALESCE function.

```
const query = await con.prepare( 'INSERT INTO Threads VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, COALESCE( ?, created_at ), COALESCE( ?, updated_at ) )' );

query.execute( [ null, 'The Title', 'The Post', null, null ] );
```

So if `created_at` and `updated_at` were integers, and the default values were 5 and 10, respectively, then above query would result in a row that looked something like this:

```
{ id: some_auto_number, title: 'The Title', post: 'The Post', created_at: 5, updated_at: 10 }
```

Hope this helps someone else who comes across this question!!